# How is Java Path converted to e.g. InputStream

Tags: java, file, path, nio

The java.nio.Files class has a static method named Files#newInputStream, which takes a Path instance as an input and returns an InputStream as an output. But it is unclear to me how this can be done without instantiating a File(InputStream) object. I would like to be able to make my own implementation of Path which can point to an InputStream which is not related to a File object. I would like to do this so that I can make a virtual filesystem which uses the notation of filesystems without actually depending on a filesystem. Is this possible?

Comment: The existing implementation of that method creates a `FileSystemProvider` from the `Path`, and then invokes `FileSystemProvider#newInputStream` with the `Path`.

Comment: Yes, if the question is about creating your own file system provider then java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider is the starting point.

Comment: Actually `FileSystemProvider#newInputStream` returns a `sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream` which has nothing to do with a `File` object. There is no `File` object involved here whatsoever.

Comment: I feel there is a misunderstanding in your question. A `File` object basically represents the same thing as a `Path` object, but the `Path` object is more modern and has less flaws. Both of them represent a location in a filesystem. Neither of them is a file or contains data. Creating an `InputStream` from one of them involves working with the underlying filesystem to retrieve the data in the file in that location. Neither `Path` nor `File` point to an `InputStream`. You can create an `InputStream` from the file at the location they point to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Java NIO file system API uses delegation and abstract factory patterns. At the lowest level there's the implementation of [`java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/spi/FileSystemProvider.html):

> Service-provider class for file systems. **The methods defined by the [`Files`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html) class will typically delegate to an instance of this class.** *[emphasis added]*

A `FileSystemProvider` provides instances of [`java.nio.file.FileSystem`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html):

> Provides an interface to a file system and is the factory for objects to access files and other objects in the file system.
>
> The default file system, obtained by invoking the `FileSystems.getDefault` method, provides access to the file system that is accessible to the Java virtual machine. The `FileSystems` class defines methods to create file systems that provide access to other types of (custom) file systems.
>
> **A file system is the factory for several types of objects:** *[emphasis added]*
>
> - The `getPath` method converts a system dependent path string, returning a `Path` object that may be used to locate and access a file.
> - The `getPathMatcher` method is used to create a `PathMatcher` that performs match operations on paths.
> - The `getFileStores` method returns an iterator over the underlying file-stores.
> - The `getUserPrincipalLookupService` method returns the `UserPrincipalLookupService` to lookup users or groups by name.
> - The `newWatchService` method creates a `WatchService` that may be used to watch objects for changes and events.

And then there's the [`Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html) interface:

> An object that may be used to locate a file in a file system. It will typically represent a system dependent file path.

Note that a `Path` is just that, a path. It does not necessarily represent an actual file, only the path of the file (whether it exists or not). It's similar to `java.io.File` in this regard.

When you invoke methods in the `Files` class it uses the [`Path#getFileSystem()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html#getFileSystem()) and [`FileSystem#provider()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html#provider()) methods to delegate to the `FileSystemProvider`. This API design is what allows a developer to use the `Files` class with *any implementation* of `Path` in a transparent manner. It doesn't matter to the developer *how* that `InputStream` is created, only that the `InputStream` *is* created in a way consistent with the API's contracts.

The methods [`Paths#get(String,String...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Paths.html#get(java.lang.String,java.lang.String...)) and [`Path#of(String,String...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html#of(java.lang.String,java.lang.String...)) delegate to the [default file system](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/FileSystems.html#getDefault()) to create the instance of `Path`. When you use those `Path` instances with the methods in `Files` you end up accessing the host platform's underlying file system.

If you want to create a virtual file system then you need to implement a `FileSystemProvider` along with all the related abstract classes and interfaces, such as `FileSystem` and `Path`. Though note some of the API is "optional". If your implementation doesn't provide the optional API then you can throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`. The Javadoc of the various classes/methods gives more information.

That said, there's already an in-memory file system implementation out there: https://github.com/google/jimfs

---

"*But it is unclear to me how this can be done without instantiating a File(InputStream)*". The NIO file API is not related to `java.io.File`. If you want to see how it does what it does you can look at the source code. Your JDK should have come with a `src.zip` file which contains the Java source files; however, it will only contain the implementation for your host operating system and won't contain any of the native code (the default file systems ultimately use native code to communicate with the underlying OS' file system).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I had heard of JimFS, but did not know how it implemented the interface such that the filesystem was in-memory.